# How to convert a string into a type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi so I'm trying to convert a string named compToAdd into a type and im not sure how to do it, I tried googling for almost 5 hours now and here I am.

The goal would be to make `slot.AddComponent<compToAddType>();`  run properly

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    public string foundationComp;
    public string turretComp;

    public void buildFoundation()
    {
        Build(foundationComp);
    }

    public void buildTurret()
    {
        Build(turretComp);
    }

    public void Build(string compToAdd)
    {      
        Type compToAddType = Type.GetType(compToAdd); //I thought this line would convert the string into a type
        slot.AddComponent<compToAddType>(); // but then I get an error here saying that compToAddType is a variable thats being used like a type..so how am I supposed to convert it?
//just note that 'slot' here have no problem and is a gameobject the problem is on the word 'compToAddType'
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the exact value of `compToAdd`?

Comment: Type.GetType() returns the type of the object you pass as parameter. Is there a reason you want to do this using strings?

Comment: when you look at the docs for `GetType` you´ll notice how assemblies are resolved. This means `GetType` will only look for types within mscorlib and the currently executing assmebly, unless you specify an# assembly qualified name.

Comment: There is the type builder to build classes at runtime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder?view=net-5.0

Comment: @mjwills it changes base on which button you click. between "Foundation" or "Turret"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general see [`Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname).

If you don't have that you will need to at least have a reference to the Assembly in question and then use [`Assembly.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettype).

You can also get the assembly if you know at least one type from the according assembly via [`Assembly.GetAssembly(theKnownType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly)

---

That said, you can not use the **generic** version `GameObject.AddComponent<T>()` since the type-parameter of generics need to be **compile-time constant**!

You can however simply use the non-generic version of [`GameObject.AddComponent(Type)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)

```
public void Build(string compToAdd)
{      
    Type compToAddType = Type.GetType(compToAdd); 
    slot.AddComponent(compToAddType); 
}
```

(*Actually there even **was** an overload directly taking a `string` as parameter but it was deprecated.*)

---

Finally I personally would avoid it completely if possible! Instead of relying on your strings being correct, why not rather use e.g.

```
public void buildFoundation()
{
    slot.AddComponent<FoundationComponnet>();
}

public void buildTurret()
{
    slot.AddComponent<TurretComponent>();
}
```

Comment: I tried editing my code again with your code as reference and it worked like a charm as for the suggestion to avoid this completely I will be sure to keep that in mind, thanks!