# how to change a get component class base on string?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im trying to use compToGet string that have been passed through the parameter into slot.GetComponent().level++;

upgradeFoundation() will be called on button click.
and there is actually quite a lot of buttons with similar functionality (like: upgradeTurret(), upgradeTurret2(), etc)
thats why im trying to **change the value of compToget string base on which button you click and use that new string to get component under the name of that new string** but it seems it doesn't work that way and I dont know how it would work any other way, any help would be much appreciate.

```
    public void upgradeFoundation()
    {
        float upgFoundationCost = slotGroup.transform.Find(slotName).gameObject.GetComponent<Slot>().upgFoundationCost;
        Upgrade(upgFoundationCost, "Foundation");
    }

    public void Upgrade(float upgCost, string compToGet)
    {
        GameObject slot = slotGroup.transform.Find(slotName).gameObject;

        if (inGameUIManagerScript.money >= upgCost)
        {
            Type compToGetType = Type.GetType(compToGet); //im not sure how to convert a string into a type
            slot.GetComponent<compToGetType>().level++; //this is the error line saying im treating a var like a type
        }

    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly the same issue as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65883043/how-to-convert-a-string-into-a-type) => **You can not use the generic!** Instead use `GetComponent(compToGetType);`

However I removed the duplicate since you still would need to **cast** to your actual type which is anything but trivial!

=> **Again** I can only recommend: **Don't use strings!**

---

Rather have a common Base class or interface like e.g.

```
public abstract class BaseComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int level;
    // public read-only access
    public int Level => level;

    public virtual void Upgrade()
    {
        level++;
    }

    // Other properties and methods all your components have in common
    // Also get into "virtual" and "abstract" members!
}
```

and inherit your stuff from it like

```
public class Foundation : BaseComponent
{
    // Additional stuff specific to the foundation
    // overrides for the virtual and abstract members
}

public class Turret : BaseComponent
{
    // Additional stuff specific to the turret
    // overrides for the virtual and abstract members
}

//Maybe this would even inherit from Turret instead?
public class Turret2 : BaseComponent
{
    // Additional stuff specific to the turret2
    // overrides for the virtual and abstract members
}
```

and finally use that common base instead:

```
public void UpgradeComponent()
{
    slot.GetComponent<BaseComponent>().Upgrade();
}
```